# Bad mouse, good mouse

Tags: mathematics, probability

In a certain city, there are only two companies (called *Company A* and *Company B*), that manufacture computer mice.

The computer mice from *Company A* last $x$ hours before needing to be recharged, while the computer mice from *Company B* last $y$ hours before needing to be recharged.

$a$% of the computer mice in this city are made by *Company A*, and all the rest are made by *Company B.*

What is the expected length of time that a randomly purchased, completely unlabeled (thus of an unknown manufacturer) computer mouse will last for before recharging, assuming it is purchased from the local electronics store within this city, and assuming the store sells only computer mice from these two companies, and nothing else?

Comment: Are you sure this qualifies for the story tag?

Comment: Also, doesn't this heavily depend on the total number of mice?

Comment: Looks to me like a mathematics problem, not a puzzle.

Comment: @CipherRiddle: This can be solved with elementary mathematics. There is no "sudden insight" or "flash of inspiration" that characterizes any puzzle, which is why I do not feel hesitant in my voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it would be

> $\frac{a}{100}x+(1-\frac{a}{100})y$

> If $a$% of the mice are made by *Company A*,
> then there is a $\frac{a}{100}$ probability that a randomly selected mouse
> was made by *Company A*,
> and a $(1-\frac{a}{100})$ probability that it was made by *Company B*. 
> Expected value is probability times value, so this expected value is
> $$\begin{align}&P(\text{mouse was made by }\textit{Company A})\times(\text{duration of }\textit{Company A}\text{ mice})\\&~~~~+P(\text{mouse was made by }\textit{Company B})\times(\text{duration of }\textit{Company B}\text{ mice})\end{align}$$
>
> As an image:
>  [image: the same formula]
>
> which is the formula I gave above.

Comment: Works for me in both IE and Firefox. And seriously?  You think taking a hatchet to my answer five minutes after asking me to change it is appropriate?

Comment: No, I didn’t take the total number of computer mice into account.  Oh my gosh, ***that changes everything!***  My answer is incomplete!  I didn’t state that, if the total number of computer mice is zero, then the expected length of time that a randomly purchased, completely unlabeled computer mouse will last for before recharging ***is undefined!*** Otherwise, multiply the answer I gave by *n* / *n*, for any non-zero value of *n* — i.e., it doesn’t matter.     :-)     ⁠

Comment: [@CipherRiddle](https://www.google.com/#q=define+irony)    :-)   ⁠